# Problema al intentar validar si se ha seleccionado o no una fila de un TreeView

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Hice un programa el cual tiene una tabla que muestra el id y el importe, con 2 botones, eliminar y actualizar.

Escribí un `try-except` para cuando no se seleccione ningún valor que salga un mensaje que diga que tiene que seleccionar un importe. Cuando lo hago con el de eliminar me sale directamente que el importe fue eliminado, como si no notara este error y siguiera con el código. Y cuando aprieto el de actualizar sale este error:

> IndexError: string index out of range

justamente me sale en esta linea:

```
old_price = self.tree.item(self.tree.selection())['values'][0]
```

Acá dejo el código:

```
def delete_product(self):
    self.mesagge['text'] = ''
    try:
        self.tree.item(self.tree.selection())['text']
    except IndexError as e:
        self.mesagge['text'] = 'Selecciona un importe'
        return
    self.mesagge['text'] = ''
    name = self.tree.item(self.tree.selection())['text']
    query = 'DELETE FROM importes WHERE id = ?'
    self.run_query(query, (name, ))
    self.mesagge['text'] = 'El importe fue eliminado'
    self.get_products()


def edit_product(self):
    self.mesagge['text'] = ''
    try:
        self.tree.item(self.tree.selection())['text']
    except IndexError as e:
        self.mesagge['text'] = 'Selecciona un importe'
        return
    old_price = self.tree.item(self.tree.selection())['values'][0]
    self.edit_wind = Toplevel()
    self.edit_wind.title("Editar importe")

    # Old Price
    Label(self.edit_wind, text = 'Importe actual').grid(row=0, column=1)
    Entry(self.edit_wind, textvariable= StringVar(self.edit_wind, value = old_price), state='readonly').grid(row=0, column=2)
    # New Price
    Label(self.edit_wind, text='Nuevo importe').grid(row=1, column=1)
    new_price = Entry(self.edit_wind)
    new_price.grid(row=1, column=2)
    # Button
    Button(self.edit_wind, text='Actualizar', command = lambda: self.edit_records(new_price.get(), old_price)).grid(row=2, column=2, sticky=W+E)


def edit_records(self, new_price, old_price):
    query = 'UPDATE importes SET importe = ? WHERE importe = ?'
    parameters = (new_price, old_price)
    self.run_query(query, parameters)
    self.edit_wind.destroy()
    self.mesagge['text'] = "El importe fue actualizado"
    self.get_products()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es que no se produce ningún `IndexError`. El método `ttk.TreeView.item` genera un diccionario de la forma:

```
{'text': '', 'image': '', 'values': '', 'open': 0, 'tags': ''}
```

cuando no hay filas selecionadas. Esto hace que `name` sea una cadena vacía (valor de la clave `"text"`), no hay ningún error de indizado porque no indizas.

En el segundo caso como "values" es una cadena vacía y el try pasó, al hacer

```
old_price = self.tree.item(self.tree.selection())['values'][0]
```

lo que intentas hacer en realidad es indizar sobre una cadena vacía:

```
""[0]
```

con el lógico `IndexError`, esta vez si, pero no es capturado por ningún `try-except`.

No uses un `try-except`, aprovechate de que **`self.tree.selection` retorna una tupla vacía si no hay filas seleccionadas**:

```
def delete_product(self):
    if (rows:= self.tree.selection()):
        name = self.tree.item(rows)['text']
        self.mesagge['text'] = ''
        query = 'DELETE FROM importes WHERE id = ?'
        self.run_query(query, (name, ))
        self.mesagge['text'] = 'El importe fue eliminado'
        self.get_products()
    else:
        self.mesagge['text'] = 'Selecciona un importe'
```

---

```
def edit_product(self):
    self.mesagge['text'] = ''
    if (rows:= self.tree.selection()):
        old_price = self.tree.item(rows)['values'][0]
        self.edit_wind = Toplevel()
        self.edit_wind.title("Editar importe")
        # Resto del código....

    else:
        self.mesagge['text'] = 'Selecciona un importe'
```

Comment: El de editar ya se soluciono, pero el de eliminar, cuando apreto en el boton sin seleccionar me sale este error: TypeError: delete_product() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given.

Comment: Hola  @LucasLeone, tenía un error tipográfico al copiar el código, faltaba self como argumento del método (además le había cambiado el nombre). Corregido. Debe ser `def delete_product(self):` no `def delete_product():`

Comment: Hola @FJsevilla, le habia cambiado el nombre a delete_product pero nunca vi que no estaba el self. El programa ya quedo terminado y completamente funcional. Muchas gracias!

Comment: No se porque pero de la nada me empezo a salir el error bitmap "pan.ico" not defined, que es por el icono pero no se porque.

Comment: Eso ya es otro problema, la primera causa es que la ruta a la imagen o el nombre no sea correcta. Si no consigues resolverlo crea una nueva pregunta con el código relevante y el erro completo. Por cierto, considera aceptar la respuesta a tus preguntas que consideres que mejor solventa tu problema, esto ayudará a otros usuarios con el mismo problema a determinar su utilidad. Para saber cómo funciona y cómo hacerlo mirarte: ----> [¿Cómo funciona la aceptación de respuestas?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/428/15089) <-------. Un saludo.